# javascript focus problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 3 fields. Country, state and users

[image: none]

I am trying to do the following. when United states is selected as a country, the state field will show. The problem is that when i use the tab key on the keyboard, it is skipping the state field and its going on the users field. So i tried using the focus property so when i select United states, the state will show + selected, but I had no luck.. Below please find the code I am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#cmbCountries").change(function () {
    $("#cmbCountries option:selected").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "United States") {               

            $("#cmbstate").show(); 
            $("#cmbstate").focus(); 

        }

        else {
            $("#cmbstate").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();   });
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chek [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Maynz/5/) out

And javascript

```
$(function (){

    $("#cmbstate").hide();

    $("#cmbCountries").change(function () {
        if($(this).val() == 'US')
        {
            $("#cmbstate").show();
            $('#cmbstate').focus()
        }
        else{
            $("#cmbstate").hide();
            $('#users').focus();
        }
    })


})
```

And html

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="first" />
<select id="cmbCountries">
    <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="OTHER1">OTHER1</option>
</select>
 <select id="cmbstate">
     <option value="value">Value 1</option>         
     <option value="value">Value 2</option>
     <option value="value">Value 3</option>
</select>
<select id="users">
    <option value="asf">asdfasdf</option>
    <option value="fadfas">sdffd</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: not working :( the state field is showing when US is selected but its being skipped when I press on TAB while Countries is selected.

Comment: @Rene Zammit what do you want exactly ?

Comment: Basically I am selecting United states in countries field..Now after that when I press TAB to go to the States field (States field will be only visible when United States is selected in Countries field) it goes to Users field instead of the States field.

Answer (score 0):

The Tabindex values must be wrong, try and manually set the Tabindex of each input to 0, 1, 2 respectively and then you should be able to tab between them easily

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#cmbCountries").change(function () {
    $("#cmbCountries option:selected").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "United States") {               

            $("#cmbstate").show(); 
            $("#cmbstate").select();
        }

        else {
            $("#cmbstate").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();   });
```

changed `focus()` to `select()`

I had once done this in my project also which worked for me.